How does highly imbalanced test data in certain splits of k-fold time-series cross-validation affect model performance?
I am working on a time-series classification (TSC) problem using k-fold time-series cross-validation (TSCV) to evaluate the performance of my models. My training data for each split is fairly balanced, class distributions ranging from 40% to 60% with a few rare cases of 30/70%. However, I noticed that the test data in some splits is highly imbalanced. For instance, in a 6-fold TSCV setup, splits 2, 5, and 6 have highly imbalanced test sets. I am concerned about how this imbalance might affect my model evaluation.
Here is a brief overview of my setup:
Class Distribution in Training and Testing Data:
Training data: Balanced (40-60% class distribution). Testing data: Highly imbalanced in certain splits (e.g., splits 2, 5, and 6). I'm using standard metrics to evaluate performance; Accuracy, Precision, Recall, F1 Score, AUC-ROC score.
I use the walk-forward time-series cross-validation method to split the data. I used Python with pandas and scikit-learn to analyze the class distribution and model performance across splits. I've used models like LSTM-FCN, InceptionTime, ResNet, TCN, and ROCKET for TSC. In this example, I am working with time series data where each time step represents a data point in a series. The target variable, Fault_Status, indicates whether a fault is present (1) or not (0) at each time step.
Below is a dummy example related to my problem and it is not the actual dataset. It only serves as a means to convey the point.
Specific Questions:

Impact on Experiment:

How might the imbalanced test data in certain splits (e.g., splits 2, 5, and 6) affect the overall evaluation of my TSC models?

Mitigation Strategies:

What strategies can I use to mitigate the negative effects of this imbalance?
Is stratified splitting appropriate for TSC, and how can I implement it?
Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

def walk_forward_tscv(X, y, n_splits=7):
    tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=n_splits)
    splits = []
    
    for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(tscv.split(X)):
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
        
        unique, counts_train = np.unique(y_train, return_counts=True)
        train_distribution = dict(zip(unique, counts_train))
        
        unique, counts_test = np.unique(y_test, return_counts=True)
        test_distribution = dict(zip(unique, counts_test))
        
        splits.append((train_index, test_index))
        
        print(f"Split {i+1}:")
        print(f"  Training set class distribution: {train_distribution}")
        print(f"  Testing set class distribution: {test_distribution}")
        print("-" * 50)
        
    return splits



This might be a better fit for the stats site.
